# What action should a client application take after executing a command?

Tags: java, c#, architecture, client

**Background**

This question is best illustrated using an example. Say I have a client application (e.g. desktop application, mobile app, etc.) that consumes information from a web service. One of the screens has a list of products that are queried from the web service when the client application starts up and are bound to the UI element. Now, the user creates a new product. This causes the client application to send a command to the web service to add that product to a database.

**Question**

In the client application, what should happen after the command is issued and is successful? Do you:

1. Query the full product list from the service and refresh the entire product list in the client application?
2. Query just the two newly added products and add them to the product list?
3. Don't query, and instead just use the information available in the client application to create the new products in the GUI, and then add them to the list?

The same questions apply to update too. If you update a product, do you get confirmation of a successful update on the service, and then just let the GUI update the product without further requests to the service?

**Edit** - Additional details added

From initial feedback, the takeaway appears to be go with the simplest approach unless this:

1. Leads to performance concerns
2. Negatively impacts user experience

There is a major/significant portion of my application where the main way to interact with the application is to drag grid records between a number of different grids. For example, dragging a product onto another grid would create a new order, which would need to be sent to the service. Some of these grids are more complex than your standard grid. Records can be grouped, and each group can be collapsed/expanded ([see here](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-forms/grid-grouping-control)). In this case, while the grid can be refreshed from the service very quickly, this would probably lead to usability concerns. When a grid is refreshed with all new data, if the user had any groups expanded/collapsed, this would be lost.

So, while most grids in my application could probably just all be refreshed at once, the more complex ones will need to be updated more carefully. I would think this would lend to option 1 or 2 (at least for creating new records). One thought I had was that the client application could create GUIDs for new records to be sent with the application. That way, no follow-up query would need to be made to the service, as the client application would already have the unique ID. Then, the client application would just wait for a successful response from the service prior to showing the user the new record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Get the whole list

I guess it depends how costly the request/response are.  If possible and efficient, I would always choose your first option (get the whole list) until there is a performance concern.

[As the saying goes](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Michael_A._Jackson):

> - The First Rule of Program Optimization: Don't do it.
> - The Second Rule of Program Optimization – For experts only: Don't do it yet.

There is simply less scenarios to cover, less code to write, less code to maintain since you'll need the "get the whole list" service no matter what.
It also returns the "most up to date list of products" in case another client added products simultaneously.

Only pros, until there is a performance concern, *in my opinion*. These last 3 words would imply that this question will only lead to opinions and should be closed...

Comment: Thanks @Alex, I appreciate you taking the time to respond. I have edited my post to add some new details. I would love your input!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any definitive right answer; these kinds of questions need to be thought of on a case by case basis.  #3 by itself is often not an option - for example, if you need the client to have a database-generated field like an ID, it's gotta get from point A to point B somehow.  You also need to think about how you're exposing any errors to your user, because it's a terrible experience if you make it appear that everything succeeded, but you actually had an error and the product didn't really save.

Beyond that, I'd look at usability as my next criteria.  What's the experience like for your users if you refresh the list versus adding just a couple of products?  Is there a significant difference?  A lot comes down to your specific application, and also the workflow being done.  If adding products is something that is the main part of someone's job, where they may spend hours a day doing this, shaving even a second off the time is a real win for your users, while if it's an uncommon workflow that people do from time to time, the performance expectations are somewhat lower.

And last I'd look at code maintenance and complexity.  If two paths are giving relatively similar experiences, pick the one that's easier to build and maintain.

There are other options, too.  You can go with a hybrid approach - for example, maybe on the client you add the data to the product list immediately (perhaps showing some kind of "saving" indicator), while also asynchronously querying the database so you can refresh the product listing and report any errors.  Such approaches tend to be the most complex, but you might go down that route if usability demands it.

Comment: Thanks @PMV, I appreciate you taking the time to respond. I have edited my post to add some new details. I would love your input!